# Mitmproxy not capturing localhost requests

Tags: mitmproxy

I'm encountering an issue with Mitmproxy where it's not capturing any localhost requests for my .NET and Angular project. This setup was working perfectly about a week ago, but now, despite trying various troubleshooting steps over the past 10 hours, I've been unable to resolve it.

Here are the details of my setup:

- I'm using Mitmproxy version 10.2.2.
- I’m Using MacOS
- I tried old versions as well
- I tried different modes of Mitmproxy
- The project involves a .NET backend and an Angular frontend.
- I've attempted different modes and configurations within Mitmproxy, including adjusting the tls_version_client_min option.

Despite these efforts, Mitmproxy isn't capturing any requests to localhost.
I'm relatively new to using Mitmproxy, so any guidance or suggestions on how to troubleshoot and resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Most applications I know always exclude localhost from any configured proxy. Therefore I don't think this is a mitmproxy problem but a problem how you configure proxy in the client application (Angular frontend).